# Laravel 8 whereJsonContains

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

with this code I implemented a search:

```
if ($request->keyword != "") {
        $users = User::where('firstname', 'like', '%' . $request->keyword . '%')
            ->orWhere('lastname', 'like', '%' . $request->keyword . '%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $request->keyword . '%')
            ->orderBy('lastname')
            ->whereJsonContains("out", Auth::user()->id)
            ->paginate($request->total);
    } else {
        $users = User::whereJsonContains("out", Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('lastname')->paginate($request->total);
    }
```

Filtering for firstname, lastname and e-mail works fine, but the important where with "->whereJsonContains("out", Auth::user()->id)" not work. After typing "s" every User with "s" will be displayed in results.... what is wrong?

Comment: What is the structure of data in the json column? Is `out` the json column name?

Comment: Yes, `out` is json column with values e. g. [1] or [1,115]. `else` works fine with `whereJsonContains`, but ignored in the `if`

Answer (score 0):

You ay try

```php
if ($request->keyword != "") {
    $users = User::query()
        ->where(function($query) use($request){
            $query->where('firstname', 'like', '%' . $request->keyword . '%')
                ->orWhere('lastname', 'like', '%' . $request->keyword . '%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $request->keyword . '%');
        })
        ->whereJsonContains("out", Auth::user()->id)
        ->orderBy('lastname')
        ->paginate($request->total);
    } else {
        $users = User::whereJsonContains("out", Auth::user()->id)
            ->orderBy('lastname')
            ->paginate($request->total);
    }
```

Query will return records where either the **firstname**, **lastname** or **email** contains anything like `$request->keyword` and the `out` column contains the currently logged in user's id.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks a lot. Only a little change: `->where(function ($query) use ($keyword)`